# Wordpress permalink direct to image jpg?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a couple of images which I want to link to externally. (Essentially they will be used in email headers and things of that sort that are sent to users).

I uploaded them in the wordpress media library and edited their slugs, so I have nice permalinks like:

`www.example.com/image1`

However when I enter that URL in the browser I just get the "This page doesn't seem to exist." page.

Permalinks for normal posts work fine.

The links to the actual image works fine too, but it is ugly (and shows unnecessary details like the fact that it is backed by wordpress and the date etc.), something like:

`www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/v2_2.jpg`

Is there a way to permalink directly to the images?

Answer (score 0):

Can you actually see the slug on the image's media page? In my case it says "Permalink: [https://www.apothekarium.de/giftschein_arsen_1877/"](https://www.apothekarium.de/giftschein_arsen_1877/%22) when I go to the media library, then click on the image, then click "edit image" and then click "edit more details".

However, even if you get this right, I think the result may not be what you are after. Look at my link: https://www.apothekarium.de/giftschein_arsen_1877/

While it does work, it does not show the image itself, but a page that contains the image. So this would be completely unsuitable for linking to it from an external site and I suppose that is what you are after.

So my answer to your question, as I understood it, is: no, that does not seem to be possible in Wordpress proper.

You could of course solve the problem externally, e. g. in your webserver config.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).